# how let User decide which object to inject through winform?

Tags: oop, design-patterns, castle-windsor

If I've class X that uses interface I which is implemented by classes A, B, C, ... where one of them is injected into into X based on user selection through winform user interface. How to let the user decide the injected class A or B or C ?

Comment: It would seem easier to just pass the correct class into the constructor of X (or use a regular setter) instead of using an IoC container for this. Even if you may be able to solve it using a registered factory, an IoC container isn't really a good match for this use case.

Comment: You could try design pattern Y or Z.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend looking into using an [object factory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_%28software_concept%29) instead. This probably be a lot simpler and readable. The factory itself could be injected, though.

If you really want to use the container to solve this, you probably could use [scopes](http://docs.castleproject.org/Windsor.Whats-New-In-Windsor-3.ashx)